# How do I espose ebike LWC components for Experiece Builder site Guest and Autrhenticated users

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, force.com-sites

I have tried opening up all object and apex permission for both but i keep getting the message "There are no products matching your current selection" on the product tile list. While the component is available and displays product tile items for my account as the system administrator, it fails to display for any other accounts.
[image: Message displayed]

Comment: try sharing of the object

Answer (score 0):

Guest user sharing rules are a special case, requiring a sharing rule to be defined. See this article for details: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_sharing_rules_guest.htm

Sharing for authenticated experience users depends on the type of licence - experience cloud utilises community cloud licencing.
For Partner and Community Plus licencing, standard sharing rules can be implemented.
Standard Community licences require the use of sharing sets, article for reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_setting_light_users.htm&type=5

You'll also need to ensure all of the profiles in use (including guest user profile) have the appropriate object and field level permissions.